# Access Sybase #temp table created in one proc from a sub procedure

Tags: sybase

I have created a # table in TestProc and calling SubProc within TestProc. Now, with SubProc, I am trying to refer the # table that I created in TestProc. Is it possible? Below code for your reference:

```
-- Main Procedure
create procedure TestProc (
      @id smallint,
      @name varchar
 ) as
 select id, name into #myTab from myTable
 exec SubProc @rVal output

 -- Sub Procedure
 create procedure SubProc (
      @rVal integer output
 ) as 
 select @rVal=count(1) from #myTab
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible and you should avoid it.

You can put create the table in tempdb database but I advice you to also avoid it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is entirely possible though not ideal but this is one of the ways wherein you could fully utilise the index creation on the 'parent' proc when using it under the 'child' proc.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.